# Should $digest be called manually in Angular 1.4?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating an app with Angular 1.4 and the New Router with components. However I observed that changing value of a variable within $scope or this inside a controller doesn't propagate the value to the template.

I called $scope.$digest() manually and everything worked. Is this the way to be?

This is my code. (main controller)

```
function appController ($router, authService, $scope) {
  $scope.alex1 = 'salut1';
  this.alex2 = "salut2";
  $router.config ([
      { path: '/home', components: {'main' : 'home'}},
      { path: '/account', components: {'main' : 'account' }},
      { path: '/campaigns', components: {'main' : 'campaigns' }},
      { path: '/login', components: {'main' : 'login' }},
      { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' }
  ]);
  //
  setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.alex1 = 'salut111';
    console.log ($scope.currentUser); 
    $scope.$digest();
  }, 2000);
}
```

Without calling $digest the value of alex1 was not updating inside the template.

Comment: Use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`. It'll trigger a digest automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not in Angular version but in `setTimeout` which runs outside the Angular digest loop. You should use `$timeout` service instead.